# Python list formatting

Tags: python, list, tabs, formatting, alignment

I have a .txt file with this on it (plus more names):

```
Boston Americans
New York Giants
Chicago White Sox
Chicago Cubs
Chicago Cubs
Pittsburgh Pirates
```

I created a list, then did a count for how many times i get the same team.

Then i got this:

```
[['New York Giants', 5], ['Anaheim Angels', 1], ['Detroit Tigers', 4], ['St. Louis Cardinals', 11], ['Minnesota Twins', 2], ['Florida Marlins', 2], ['Boston Red Sox', 7], ['Oakland Athletics', 4], ['Los Angeles Dodgers', 5], ['Philadelphia Athletics', 5]
```

How can I turn that list to come out like this:

```
New York Giants (\t tab) 5
Anaheim Angels (tab) 1
Detroit Tigers  (tab) 4            <----- with all the numbers centered
St. Louis Cardinals (tab) 11
Minnesota Twins (tab) 2
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Simply join your nested lists with the `'\t'` string:

```
newlist = ['\t'.join(map(str, sublist)) for sublist in outerlist]
```

The `map(str, ...)` is needed to convert your counts to strings first.

The numbers won't necessarily be centered, however; tab characters move the 'cursor' to the next tab position, which may be earlier than you expect if the preceding text is not long enough.

You could simply use string formatting to pad out the first column with spaces; you could base this on the maximum length of the first column:

```
max_team_width = max(len(item[0]) for item in outerlist)
max_count_width = max(len(str(item[1])) for item in outerlist)
for item in outerlist:
    print('{item[0]:{team_width}} {item[1]:{count_width}d}'.format(
        team_width=max_team_width, count_width=max_count_width, item=item))
```

This *prints* the items, but you could also just append the result to a list still.

The latter produces:

```
>>> team_counts = [
...     ['New York Giants', 5],
...     ['Anaheim Angels', 1],
...     ['Detroit Tigers', 4],
...     ['St. Louis Cardinals', 11],
...     ['Minnesota Twins', 2],
... ]
>>> max_team_width = max(len(item[0]) for item in team_counts)
>>> max_count_width = max(len(str(item[1])) for item in team_counts)
>>> for item in team_counts:
...     print('{item[0]:{team_width}} {item[1]:{count_width}d}'.format(
...         team_width=max_team_width, count_width=max_count_width, item=item))
... 
New York Giants      5
Anaheim Angels       1
Detroit Tigers       4
St. Louis Cardinals 11
Minnesota Twins      2
```

while the tab-separate output could be produced with:

```
>>> for item in team_counts:
...     print('\t'.join(map(str, item)))
... 
New York Giants 5
Anaheim Angels  1
Detroit Tigers  4
St. Louis Cardinals 11
Minnesota Twins 2
```

Comment: how would i convert the list to str in: newlist = ['\t'.join(sublist) for sublist in outerlist]

Comment: @adrianhmartinez: you could just use `for sublist in outerlist: print('\t'.join(sublist))` to print out the tab-joined strings.

Comment: when i do newlist = ['\t'.join(map(str,sublist)) for sublist in count] it prints the "\t" and it doesnt actually tab.

Comment: @adrianhmartinez: no, objects in lists (and other containers) use `repr()` formatting and that means characters like `\t` are shown as escapes. Print *individual strings* from the list and you'll see the tab interpreted as such.

Comment: if i dont put the (map(str it says expected str int found.

Comment: @adrianhmartinez: yes, because `str.join()` can only take strings.

Comment: but how can i turn the list into string

Comment: @adrianhmartinez what *kind* of string? You could join the lists *again* with newlines, for example: `'\n'.join(newlist)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [['New York Giants', 5], ['Anaheim Angels', 1], ['Detroit Tigers', 4], ['St. Louis Cardinals', 11], ['Minnesota Twins', 2], ['Florida Marlins', 2], ['Boston Red Sox', 7], ['Oakland Athletics', 4], ['Los Angeles Dodgers', 5], ['Philadelphia Athletics', 5]]

name = ""
score = 0

for i in list:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        if j % 2 == 0:
        name = i[j]
    else:
        score = i[j]

print("{} \t {}".format(name, score))
```

I just solved your problem very simple path. :)